# In python, is there a way to print white space over top of existing characters without overwriting them?

Tags: python, curses

I want to print a string of text separated by white space onto a visual grid that I made in curses. The problem is that the white space overwrites the grid lines. Is there a way to print a string of characters and add white space that DOESN'T overwrite anything that may be previously written on the screen? Also, I can't write the grid lines after the string as it would bog down the performance of the program.

Comment: Only one character at a time may be visible at any window location.  Why would you write whitespace anywhere if you didn't mean to blank it?

Comment: Grid lines?  Maybe you could include an example of what you want to see.